# Code referencing internal library not working

Tags: java, android, xml, shared-libraries

I am trying to make my first library to learn and see how things work. What is supposed to happen is that my main activity (in the sample or whatever app uses the local library) will show a loading animation from the library. But when I add in the code, it does not show in the sample. I'm not getting any errors or anything. What could be going on?

Sample Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar spinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   //This is what isnt working. The spinner 
 spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(com.marlonjones.ezloadanimlibrary.R.id.main_progress);
```

library XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/main_progress"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/main_ind_progress"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

main_ind_progress:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <animated-rotate    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/loader_main"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"/>
```

The drawable main_ind_progress, and the drawable loader_main are both inside of the library.

All code: https://github.com/MJonesDev/EZLoadAnimLibrary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ProgressBar` view isn't added to your current Activity i.e. you have no view of the type `ProgressBar` that is why it isn't showing anything

You can assign an id to the root `RelativeLayout` in the `content_main` layout file of your current Activity then in the `OnCreate()` method

```
   RelativeLayout rL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
   // and then add your spinner to the relative layout
   rL.addView(snipper);
```

or what you can do is make a `ProgressBar` in your current app's `content_main.xml` file

```
   <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/my_progress_bar"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
   />
```

and assign it the `main_ind_progress to` it from your library

```
   ProgressBar spinner=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.your_progress_bar_id);
   spinner.setIntermediateDrawable(com.marlonjones.ezloadanimlibrary.R.drawable.main_ind_progress);
```

Comment: I'll try this out when I get home from work. If it works, I'll let you know and mark it as an answer.